# Bright green highlight in Android Studio

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

I got this bright green highlight in some code I wrote:

[image: screenshot]

What is Android Studio trying to tell me?

There is no corresponding line in the scroll bar, no gutter icon, no tooltip and no special Alt+Enter action.

My color scheme is set to "Classic Light". Here's what it looks like in Darcula:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Smart cast to non-nullable type, 'cause of the `msg.event!!` preceding it?

Comment: @MikeM. I don't think so. I have used not-null assertions in other places and this is the only one that lights up.

Comment: @MikeM. Actually you're on to something. I just wrote one on purpose and it lighted up as well. It doesn't seem to light up when it's a class member though.

Comment: I've noticed it a few times, and that was the only conclusion that made sense from my brief testing, but I never did really investigate it any further. It did seem a little flaky, but that could've just been from subtle code differences that I hadn't realized at the time.

Comment: (minus one) for using Classic Light :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a smart-cast that is occurring because you have asserted that `event` is not null. The `event` property of the message class must be immutable, meaning it is both a `val` and has no custom getter. (Or it might be a final field defined in a Java class.)

Smart-casting only happens for local variables (not captured in an enclosure) and immutable properties (defined in the same module or marked `private`), because otherwise the compiler cannot guarantee that the value hasn't changed since its type/nullability was last asserted.

Answer (score 0):

To disable this inspection, navigate to `Editor -> Color Scheme -> Kotlin -> Smart-casts` and uncheck background for each type

[image]